# Mocking local function from another file

Tags: python, mocking, patch, python-unittest

I need to patch a function imported from the same file containing another function I want to test, but it's not working =/.

```py
# funcs.py

def func_one():
    return 1


def func_two():
   return func_one() + 2
```

```py
from .funcs import func_two

class TestFunc(TestCase):
    def test_func_two(self):
        with patch('func_one', 0):
            result = func_two()
```

The `result` should be two but I got an error with the test:

```
TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'func_one'
```

Comment: You need to patch ``.func_one`` of ``.funcs``, not of your current module.

Answer (score 1):

I need to import the absolute path of the function:

```py
from .funcs import func_two

class TestFunc(TestCase):
    def test_func_two(self):
        @patch('funcs.func_one', MagicMock(return_value=0)):
            result = func_two()
```

Where `funcs.func_one` is the *entire module path + func name*.

Comment: @patch should be above the test fucntion and you will need to pass in a parameter as well if using decorator. Also you don't need to user `MagicMock(return_value=0)`, can just use `@patch('funcs.func_one', return_value=0)`